# Can I find and replace in LESS import?

Tags: less

I want to nest a css framework inside a div in order to provide a scoped namespace like this:

```
.myframework {
  @import url("myframework.css");
}
```

However, the framework has rules for <html> and <body> tags, so the above code would compile to:

```
.myframework html { ... }
.myframework body { ... }
```

This won't do. I could manually change any such references, but then I'd have to do this manually everytime there is an update to the framework. Is there an equivalent to find/replace in LESS that I can apply to an @import statement like this:

```
/* psedudocode */
.myframework {
  str_replace( ( @import url("myframework.css") ), 'html', '.myframework-html';
}
```

which would compile to:

```
.myframework .myframework-html { ... }
```

The idea is that I could then scope the framework like this:

```
<html>

  <body>

    No framework styles applied here

    <div class="myframework">
      <div class="myframework-html">
        <div class="myframework-body">

          Framework styles are applied here

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Additionally, I'd probably have use some regex to ensure that only html and body TAGS are affected, not class names, url() paths, etc.

Comment: I use SASS personally, but I haven't settled on a framework yet (bootstrap, semantic-ui, etc.), so I'm interested in solutions in both. However, I could always compile from LESS, and then do a SASS find/replace on the compiled css (or vice-versa for a SASS-based framework).

Comment: Ok, let's go with LESS since Bootstrap and Semantic-UI are both based on LESS. I will amend the question to be more specific to LESS.

Comment: This kind of preprocessing is somewhat beyond the purpose of either CSS preprocessor (since they are made primarily to create new CSS styles raither than to *hack existing CSS code*... At least Less is the least "string/text processing" one of those. So make sure the word "preprocessor" does not mislead you there).

Answer (score 0):

Although not in LESS, this may be a better solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-css-selectors

This grunt plugin will add prefix .foo to all css selectors, but html/body selectors will be replaced with .foo instead. This way, I can compile from LESS or SASS, and then run the prefix command separately.